# Про *wait_event_interruptible*

Tags: linux, c, драйвер

Ранее, при разработке драйверов, я не пользовался *wait_event_interruptible(...)*, но сейчас появилось желание попробовать. И никак не могу понять смысл второго параметра:

- Это флаг засыпания
- Это флаг пробуждения

В "библии" LDD3 от Jonathan Corbet пишется (с моей точки зрения) невнятно. Там используется английское двойное отрицание, которое можно перевести и так и эдак. В русском переводе написано "пока condition оценивается как истинное значение, процесс продолжает спать."

Пример, который он приводит в крошечном драйвере sleepy.c

```
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wq);
static int flag = 0;

ssize_t sleepy_read (struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "process %i (%s) going to sleep\n",
            current->pid, current->comm);
    wait_event_interruptible(wq, flag != 0);
    flag = 0;
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "awoken %i (%s)\n", current->pid, current->comm);
    return 0; /* EOF */
}

ssize_t sleepy_write (struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count,
        loff_t *pos)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "process %i (%s) awakening the readers...\n",
            current->pid, current->comm);
    flag = 1;
    wake_up_interruptible(&wq);
    return count; /* succeed, to avoid retrial */
}
```

вроде-бы подтверждает этот тезис.

Однако, если посмотреть текст этого макроса, то (IMHO) получается - наоборот:

```
#define wait_event_interruptible(wq, condition)               \
({                                                            \
    int __ret = 0;                                            \
    if (!(condition))                                         \
        __wait_event_interruptible(wq, condition, __ret);     \
    __ret;                                                    \
})
```

Чего я не понимаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это «флаг пробуждения» (хотя термин «условие» подходит больше т.к. это всё же выражение в макросе).

В английской версии ИМХО всё предельно очевидно написано, что в документации в комментария в ядра:

> @condition: a C expression for the event to wait for
>   ...
>   The process is put to sleep (TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE) until the @condition evaluates to true.
>
> ---
>
> *@condition: C-выражение, которого ожидает процесс
>
>   ...
>
>   Процесс усыпляется(TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE) до тех пор пока @condition не будет истинным.*

Что в LDD3:

> until condition evaluates to a true value, the process continues to sleep
>
> ---
>
> *Пока условие не станет истинным, процесс будет спать*

Пример с этим полностью согласуется; не вижу, как этого можно было незаметить... Разве что, из-за того, что вопрос просто задан поздним вечеров/ранним утром можно было посчитать не все отрицания.

А в русском переводе, очевидно, ошибка... на сколько я понимаю, он не официальный и приведённый пример не единственное его огрех... При желании по этому поводу можно попробовать связаться с его автором и указать на ошибку...

Comment: *А в русском переводе, очевидно, ошибка* -  я не силён в английском, но меня это место насторожило.  Спасибо за ответ! Буду сейчас проверять на практике. По результату - поставлю галку на Ваш ответ.

Comment: Проверил - всё, как  Вы сказали!